# How do I see trigger functions in the log files

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have a table `charass` on this table I have a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER charassheattrigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.charass
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public._charassheattrigger();
```

The function executed by this trigger looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._charassheattrigger()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$

BEGIN

  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.charass_value <> NEW.charass_value)) AND NEW.charass_char_id = 34 THEN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT true FROM heat WHERE heat_number = NEW.charass_value) THEN
      INSERT INTO heat (heat_number,heat_created,heat_vend_id) 
        SELECT NEW.charass_value,NOW(), order_vend_id
        FROM ls
        JOIN detail ON (ls_id = detail_ls_id)
        JOIN hist ON (detail_hist_id = hist_id)
        JOIN order ON (hist_order_id = order_id)
        WHERE hist_ordtype = 'PO' AND hist_transtype = 'RP' AND ls_id = NEW.charass_target_id;
    END IF;
  END IF;  

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

When I look at the log file. I can see the statement executed

`statement: INSERT INTO charass (charass_value, charass_target_type, charass_target_id, charass_char_id) VALUES ('123456789', 'LS', 1234, 34)`

I check the heat table expecting to see a record with the heat_number as '123456789' but nothing is in the heat table.

So i then open up pg admin and copy the above statement and execute it manually. Now there is a record in the heat table.

What is the difference between the manual insert and the one done by the application. Is there a way to tell? the username behind the statement is the same so it cant be a permission thing. I was wondering if there was some way to send information from the trigger function to the log file so I can review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `auto_explain` to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf` as well as these additional parameters:

```
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0
```

Then restart PostgreSQL.

Now you will get the statements inside the function logged, along with their execution plan.

Comment: is there anything that you can think of that could cause this behavior?

Comment: A bug in your logic. Looking at the statements will certainly help.

Comment: It seems that hist record is not created till later on in the transaction. auto_explain seems nice but I need to look at how to make it more precise.